# Excel VBA: How to use Application.ontime to call a click event?

Tags: vba, excel, ontime

I'd like to use the Application.ontime method to call a button_click event on my Excel form.

when i use this code I can call a sub located in my Module1:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "test"
```

However if I use this code it doesn't call my Private Sub CommandButton1_Click (it does nothing):

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "CommandButton1_Click"
```

How can I call a click on my button "CommandButton1"

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expose the desired functionality.  In a standard module enter, for example:

```
Public Sub ReallyVisibleMacro()
    MsgBox "Hello World"
End Sub
```

This sub does all the real work.  Then your button code would be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call ReallyVisibleMacro
End Sub
```

and in the OnTime code:

```
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15"), "ReallyVisibleMacro"
```

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.  I thought about something like that but I was trying to avoid to transfer the code from my Sub CommandButton1_Click to a standard module.  When I do that I'm getting an error 91 which I'm not getting when my code is not in the module.  I was hoping that I could simply call my CommanButton1_Click sub...

Comment: @sims  You might need to possibly modify the button code to avoid using button-specific thing like `Me`

Comment: Thanks Gary.  I did make the correction to get rid of the Me's but I'm still getting an error 91.  Your answer works though.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It finally worked for me. I placed all the code that was in the CommandButton1_click in a the same usrform1 as a sub called "finished".  OnTime called a sub in my Module1 which called my sub in my form by using usrform1.finished.  I know it's not elegant but it works for me.  Your help is very much appreciated!